# Install two ceentOS on the same harddrive

Tags: linux, installation, centos

I want to install two centOS V6.2 on the same Hardidsk but on different partition. After installing on different different partition, at the time of booting it shows only centOS which is installed at last.
Can some help me to install two centOS on the same Harddrive.

Comment: Hi there. As this doesn't really relate to programming, you should take your question to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using GRUB. Bootup with whatever CentOS that boots up. Open the grub.conf file (normally under /boot/grub). Find the kernel and initramfs of the other installation of CentOS.(usually under /boot)

Copy the title, root, kernel and initrd lines in grub.conf file, and paste those lines after the existing ones. Make changes to the newly pasted lines. Change the title to reflect the text in the new menu. Change root to the / of the other installation partition in GRUB terms. Change the kernel and initrd params to reflect the location of other kernel and initramfs.

Delete the line 'hiddenmenu' and increase the timeout to display GRUB menu properly. Save the changes and reboot.